# what color would a pure sulfuric acid ocean be?

Tags: chemistry

On a planet with no water or oxygen or anything to react with the sulfuric acid, what color would an ocean of it be? I know sulfuric acid is clear, but water is also clear, and oceans are blue, not clear, so what color would a sulfuric acid ocean be?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

The information required is the visible light absorption spectrum of pure sulfuric acid, but unfortunately this seems to be a very difficult thing to find. Plenty of stuff about UV and IR absorption spectra out there, but no visible light information. Without that, you can't really work out what color the stuff will be in bulk. You might have more luck asking the chemistry stackexchange.

I'm going to write an answer anyway, because this matters less that you think it does.

> on a planet with no water or oxygen or anything to react with the sulfuric acid...

Problem one: sulfuric acid contains all the ingredients you need to *make* water and oxygen. Subject it to the right environment and the stuff will just start appearing for free! Consider [UV and visible light photolysis](http://www.issibern.ch/teams/venusso2/multimedia/pdf/Zhang_10b.pdf) for example, which converts sulfuric acid in Venus' atmosphere to water and sulfur oxides. You get recombination of course, but there's always gonna be some water there.

Problem two: pretty much *everything* reacts with sulfuric acid, and the universe is full of things which which just love to react with acid. The planet on which your ocean is found has a good chance of containing lots of metals of various kinds... the solar system is full of iron and aluminum, to name just two examples.

These metals react with the acid to produce brightly colored sulfates in solution, so unless your acid world is basically a frozen snowball at the outer edge of a planetary system it seems likely to have red or orange or brown tinted oceans, reflecting skies tinted brown by sulfate aerosols.

Comment: Well, maybe a K3 civilization made a planet of pure sulfuric acid as an art project.....

Comment: @LorenPechtel "_maybe a god/wizard did it and ran away_" is not a particularly useful or satisfying answer, even if it could be used to answer pretty much every question on this site.

Comment: It was a way of saying that it would never happen naturally--you'll never have an ocean of pure sulfuric acid unless some immensely powerful entity made it.

Comment: @LorenPechtel ...in which case it'll be whatever color the godwizard wants it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago I happened to be walking around a long abandoned mine site that mined pyrite (iron sulfide FeS<sub>2</sub>) during the 1950s. The site contained numerous piles of waste material that contained unrecovered pyrite.

When rain fell some of the pyrite in the piles of waste would oxidize and form sulfuric acid. Pools containing the run-off had a reddish tinge, similar to pictures one sees of [Rio Tinto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rio_Tinto_(river)) in Spain.

[image]

It's easy to see why the Spanish call it Rio Tinto (The River Red)

**Pure** sulfuric acid in a **glass** container will be clear because it is not reacting with anything.

The color of the acidic waters in the environment will not solely be due to the color of sulfuric acid. They will also be tinted by minerals and metals that have been dissolved by the acid.

The reddish pools I observed were in "soil", more accurately regolith, a geological substance. Waters of Rio Tinto in Spain also contain minerals and metals from the river bed and walls of the rivers; again geological substances.

A sea of sulfuric acid, where ever it is, will be be contained by geological substances - rocks that contain minerals. The acid of the sea will react with minerals and metals of the rock containing the sea and give it a color. If that containment geology is mostly igneous (derived from lava/magma) it will contain iron and hence it will have a reddish tinge. How red, depends on the amount of metals dissolved in the acid - the more metals the more deeper the shade of red.